# Maven War Plugin Exclusions (need to exclude an entire dir)

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I've got my project structured as such:

[image: project structure]

Here is the plugin element I'm using for the maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>webapp/resources/styleguide</packagingExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My end-goal is to include the styleguide dir when publishing to a local Tomcat server, but when packagin a WAR file using "mvn package" the styleguide will be excluded.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there more info I can provide to portray what I'm doing more clearly?

Comment: Do you need to include or to exclude this dir in resulted war?

Comment: Sorry! Just now seeing this comment....I need to exclude it